# Request file from host A that is created via PHP on host B

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

I have encrypted .txt files located on my server (Host B).
Let's say what they are encrypted with is called ENCRYPTION #1.

A user (Host A) wants to request a specific file from my server by sending over information such as filename and username. Before he should get the requested file there are a few steps to do as he can not take any use of the file in the current state (ENCRYPTION #1).

What has to be done is:

1. Open up the requested file and save the content in a variable.
2. Decrypt the content of the variable via PHP (ENCRYPTION #1 to plain text).
3. Encrypt the plain text again but this time using ENCRYPTION #2 (Plain text to ENCRYPTION #2).
4. Create a new .txt file with the content encrypted with ENCRYPTION #2.
5. Send the now with ENCRYPTION #2 encrypted .txt file back to Host A as requested.

I have the encrypting scripts and everything already done but what I do not have an idea of is how to run the .txt file through a PHP script on Host B before sending it back to Host A.

Could anyone here point me to a direction that helps me get this done or show me some kind of example?

Comment: `fopen()` or `file_get_contents()` should work for you.

Comment: The problem that I have is that the admin of Host A may not see the actual encrypting PHP script content.
What he does is he sends a request to my server and I want my server to run the PHP script and then send back the requested file.
I have all that stuff ready, the only part I do not get is how do I let my server run the PHP script upon request from another host.

Comment: How is the request being sent? Are you exposing an API or REST service?

Comment: The website on host A is basically a pannel a user is logged in to.
Every script that the user has access to has an own download button.
By pressing that download button a PHP script is run and a request should be sent to my server and everything I wrote above should be done so the user gets the encrypted file in the end.

Comment: The PHP script is run on the requesting server, so perhaps you could use cURL to make the request to the remote.